# How do I POST XML using Faraday and receive response?

Tags: ruby, faraday

I am attempting to learn Ruby/Faraday.  I need to POST XML to a RESTful web service and am confused on how to do this.

I have a string containing the XML as follows:

```
require "faraday"
require "faraday_middleware"
mystring = %&<xml><auth><user userid='username' pwd='password'/></auth></xml>&
```

How do I post the XML to a URL and receive the result?  I am trying to do something like:

```
conn = Faraday.new(:url=>'http://url')
conn.post '/logon' {mystring}
```

I get the message:

```
SyntaxError: (irb):11: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting $end
conn.post '/logon' {mystring}
```

**Edit 1**
I have gotten the POST request to work.  My code is provided below.

```
require "faraday"
require "faraday_middleware"

myString = %&<xml><auth><user userid='username' pwd='password'/></auth></xml>&
myUrl = %&url&

conn = Faraday.new(:url => myUrl) do |builder|
  builder.response :logger #logging stuff
  builder.use Faraday::Adapter::NetHttp #default adapter for Net::HTTP
end

res = conn.post do |request|
  request.url myUrl
  request.body = myString
end

puts res.body
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to the documentation](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday#usage):

```
conn = Faraday.new(:url=>'http://url')
conn.post '/logon', mystring
```

There are two errors in your code. The first one is that you are missing a comma between the URL and the variable causing `{ mystring }` to be interpreted as a block.

The second error is that `mystring` already holds a string and the following code does not make sense in Ruby:

```
 { "string" }
```

Thus `conn.post '/logon', mystring` is wrong. So the final result is:

```
conn = Faraday.new(:url=>'http://url')
conn.post '/logon', mystring
```

or:

```
conn = Faraday.new(:url=>'http://url')
conn.post '/logon', { :key => mystring }
```

if you want to submit a key/value POST body. But this is not your case, because you are already posting an XML body.

Comment: How do I get the response back?  I am still looking for some "good" documentation.  Any references?

Comment: The response should be returned from the conn.post call.  See this: http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2011/07/faraday-advanced-http/